# ldapsearch output to a text file

Tags: bash, unix

I am writing a bash script to return the display names for users. When I run the command on the console, I get the display name. When I run the script, which reads inputs from a text file, I do not get the display name.

For kma@abc.com, the display name is like: Khbsd Muweu

The input text file (names.txt) contains the following data:

```
"kma@abc.com"  
"hja@abc.com"  
"dgi@abc.com"
```

The script is as below:

```
while IFS='' read -r line || [[ -n "$line" ]]
do
echo "$line"
ldapsearch -v -LLL -Y GSSAPI -H ldap://padns1.abc.com -b "dc=abc,dc=com" userPrincipalName="$line" displayName -Q | grep "displayName: .*$" | awk '{print $2,$3}'
done < "$1"
```

This script is saved as fnames.sh and the script is run as:

```
bash fnames.sh names.txt
```

The echo "$line" prints the content from the text file, but the ldapsearch command does not work. Can someone let me where I am wrong? 
I want to store the output of the command (just the display name) in a text file. How can I do that?

Comment: Have you tried adding `set -x` to your script? It's a quick way to verify that your script is doing what you expect it to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your input file actually contains those double quotes, that's what's causing the issue.

Once expanded, you'll be using `userPrincipalName=""kma@abc.com""`, that is to say, literally looking for `"kma@abc.com"` (with quotes), not `kma@abc.com` (without quotes).  You should also check that your input file is using the correct line endings.  Carriage returns mixed in can silently wreak havoc.

Comment: Mr. Llama, yes the quotes were the problem. It works after removing the quotes from the input file.

Comment: @CrazyKris - If this answer helped solve your problem, please consider [marking it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) using the check mark under the voting arrows.  Thank you!